# Mongo update query equvalent to SQL

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need equivalent mongo query to below SQL query:

```
Update tableName set tableName.col1 = tableName.col2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I had given incorrect solution earlier. As the answer is accepted, updating it with the right way

```
db.collectionName.find().snapshot().forEach(function (elem) {
        db.collectionName.update({_id: elem._id}, {$set: {col2: elem.col1}});
    }
);
```

<s>Use normal update query along wiht `$set` to set new field value</s>

```
db.collectionName.update({}, {$set: {col2: '$col1'}}, {multi: true})
```

Comment: This will update the `col2` field in all the documents in the collection to have the string literal `'$col1'`, not the value from `col1`.